# Wi-Fi router occasionally refuses to connect devices

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dir-300

I use router DLink dir-300 at home to share internet for PCs, laptop and mobile phones for about 5 years.
I had no complaints, but recently i started to face problems with Wi-Fi connections.

This is not a stable problem, sometimes access is got easily but sometimes there's no way to connect via Wi-Fi.
My network is seen by devices, but attempts to connect just fail. Ethernet connections still work though.

I'm afraid that you can't detect the problem cause just by this description, but maybe you can point me to possible problems. Firstly I thought that this is routing problem, but there are about 5 devices total (I browse them in 'active sessions' screen) and I'm pretty sure router can serve much more devices at once.

Comment: [How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks, i tried the 'change wireless channel' feature, waiting for results.

Comment: Solution with changing wireless channel didn't help